# Expressing a Function Elegantly

Tags: geometry, functions

Consider $n$ points on the plane, with each point $i$ having both a position, defined by a pair of Cartesian coordinates, $x_i$ and $y_i$, and an orientation $\theta_i\in [-\pi,\pi]$. The state of a point can therefore be represented as $\mathbf{p}_i=(x_i,y_i,\theta_i)$.

Point $i$ is said to "see" point $j$ if a line projected from point $i$ along the direction $\theta_i$ passes through a circle of radius $r$ centred around point $j$, where $r$ is a given constant. Then, the "activation" of point $i$, $f_i$, is set to $1$ if point $i$ "sees" at least one other point; $0$ otherwise.

We can write this as follows:

$f_{ij} = \begin{cases} 0\qquad \text{if point $i$ does not "see" point $j$ or if $i=j$},\\
1\qquad \text{if point $i$ "sees" point $j$},
\end{cases}$

and $f_i$ is the logical disjunction of all the $f_{ij}$'s, i.e.:

$f_i=f_{i1}\vee \dots \vee f_{in}.$

My questions are: what is the most elegant way of writing down $f_{ij}(\mathbf{p}_i,\mathbf{p}_j)$? Moreoever, is there an elegant way of expressing $f_i(\mathbf{p}_1,\dots,\mathbf{p}_n)$ that eliminates the logical disjunction (I'm not too hopeful about this last one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct me if I'm wrong, but I guess you're talking about objects that see each other depending on their line of sight (robots, characters in a game, etc.). And I guess the "fixed $r$" is the diameter of the objects (their actual size for robots or their "hitbox" for characters, etc.).

If I'm right then you should add another property to the problem:

> No point $(x_i,y_i)$ can be within $r$ of another point $(x_j,y_j)$.

Otherwise with your definition, if a point is already in a circle of radius $r$ around another point, then it "sees" it for any angle $\theta$ because since it's already in the circle, any line projected from that point will go through the circle.

Now here is what your points and circles look like:

[image]

With these notations, you have:

$$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{r}{d}$$
$$d=\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}$$

$\alpha$ will always be in $]0,\frac{\pi}{2}[$ so:

$$\alpha=\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{d}\right)$$

Now look at your angles:

[image]

Here, the point $i$ doesn't see the point $j$. For the point $i$ to see the point $j$, the angle $\theta_i$ has to be in the interval $\large[\theta_{min},\theta_{max}]$. You can write it this way:

$$\large(f_{ij}=1)\Leftrightarrow(\theta_{min}\leq\theta_i\leq\theta_{max})$$

You also have from this diagram:

$$\large\theta_{min}=\theta_c-\alpha=\theta_c-\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{d}\right)$$
$$\large\theta_{max}=\theta_c+\alpha=\theta_c+\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{d}\right)$$
$$\large\tan(\theta_c)=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$

Ok now these are all always true. But in order to get $\theta_c$, you need to have 4 cases (which are actually really just 2 cases):

[image]

For cases 1 and 4, $\large\theta_c\in]-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}[$ so:

$$\theta_c=\arctan\left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\right)$$

For cases 2 and 3, $\large\theta_c\in]\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}[$ and so:

$$\theta_c=\arctan\left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\right)+\pi$$

You can determine in which case you are by looking at the sign of $\Delta x$. If it's positive you're in case 1 or 4, and if it's negative you're in case 2 or 3.

You might have noticed that I left two specific cases behind: $\large\theta_c=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\large\theta_c=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ (which happens when $\Delta x=0$)

Well it's pretty straightforward here because you already know $\theta_c$, no need to compute $\arctan$ or anything.

Now you have your conditions on $\theta_i$:

- If $\Delta x=0$ and $\Delta y>0$ : $\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{d}\right)\leq\theta_i\leq\frac{\pi}{2}+\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{d}\right)$
- If $\Delta x=0$ and $\Delta y<0$ : $-\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{d}\right)\leq\theta_i\leq-\frac{\pi}{2}+\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{d}\right)$
- If $\Delta x>0$ : $\arctan\left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{d}\right)\leq\theta_i\leq\arctan\left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\right)+\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{d}\right)$
- If $\Delta x>0$ : $\arctan\left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\right)+\pi-\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{d}\right)\leq\theta_i\leq\arctan\left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\right)+\pi+\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{d}\right)$

This means if one of these is true (depending on $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$), then $f_{ij}=1$

Now let's just use the notation: $\large(f_{ij}=1)\Leftrightarrow(\theta_{min,j}\leq\theta_i\leq\theta_{max,j})$

I added a $j$ subscript here because we now know that both bounds depend on which point $j$ you look at.

Let's say you have $n$ points. Take any $i\in[1,n]$. Then

$$\large(f_i=1)\Leftrightarrow(\exists j\in[1,n],j\neq i,\space\theta_{min,j}\leq\theta_i\leq\theta_{max,j})$$

If you call $I_j$ each of your intervals $\large[\theta_{min,j},\theta_{max,j}]$ you have:

[image]

And your $f_i$ is given by:

$$\large(f_i=1)\Leftrightarrow\left(\theta_i\in\bigcup_{\begin{array}{cc} j=1 \\ j\neq i\end{array}}^nI_j\right)$$

Maybe ask another question here to see if there is a simpler way of writing this condition ;) I have no clues for the moment.

Ps: if you want some simple formula for $f_i$ just "swap" the $0$ and $1$ values: $0$ when it sees, $1$ when it doesn't. Then you simply have :

$$\displaystyle f_i=\prod_{\begin{array}{cc} j=1 \\ j\neq i\end{array}}^n f_{ij}$$

Because if all $f_{ij}$ are equal to $1$ (doesn't see) then $f_i=1$ (sees nothing) and if at least one $f_{ij}$ is equal to $0$ (sees) then $f_i=0$ (sees something).